# getting git branches of a certain age

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

My organization is using git branching extensively. As a result, we have produced over 2000 branches in the past year. We are now trying to adopt a strategy for cleaning up all the old branches that are of some given age. I know how to delete branches, but I can't find a straightforward way to list all of the branches with heads of a given age. The plan is to set up a cron that periodically deletes all branches of a given age, except those that are on some list.

Has anyone tried anything like this before?

Comment: Don't think that it is possible with one command, so the only solution is to write a script.

Comment: @Dmitry: Okay, so the question is how to write that script, and in particular how to get the necessary information out of git. Moving on...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answers using committer dates are a good direction... if you want to delete branches that point to old commits. But you might want to delete branches which are actually old; if you create a branch today pointing to a commit from last year, you don't want it wiped!

So, you want to examine the reflog dates instead.

You can get a human-readable form with `git reflog show --date=local mybranch`:

```
8b733bc mybranch@{Tue Mar 22 13:21:49 2011}: commit: foo
7e36e81 mybranch@{Tue Mar 22 13:21:25 2011}: commit: bar
99803da mybranch@{Tue Mar 22 13:20:45 2011}: branch: Created from otherbranch
```

(You might also like `--date=relative`)

The entry on the top is the most recent thing that happened on that branch, so that's the bit we care about. Unfortunately, there's no log format placeholder for just the date, so to grab out just the date, we do a little work:

```
git log -g -n 1 --date=local --pretty=%gd mybranch | sed 's/.*{\(.*\)}/\1/'
# Prints "Mon Mar 21 13:23:26 2011"
```

Of course, for scripting, that's not very useful, so let's go ahead and get the epoch time instead:

```
git log -g -n 1 --date=raw --pretty=%gd mybranch | sed 's/.*{\(.*\) .*/\1/'
# Prints 1300731806
```

Now we're getting somewhere!

```
#!/bin/bash
cutoff_date=$(date --date="July 23, 2010" +%s)
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname)' | while read branch; do
    reflog_date=$(git log -g -n 1 --date=raw --pretty=%gd $branch -- | sed 's/.*{\(.*\) .*/\1/')
    if [ -n "$reflog_date" && "$reflog_date" -lt "$cutoff_date" ]; then
        git branch -D ${branch#refs/heads/}
    fi
done
```

An example script! I used `date` to convert a human-readable date for the cutoff, then for each branch, I checked if the reflog's last date was before the cutoff, and if so, deleted the branch. You could add in a check against a whitelist there, to save yourself from accidentally deleting something you care about. (Edit: if the branches are older than 90 days, this won't delete them, because their reflogs will already be empty... up to you what you want to do in that case, really. You could fall back to checking the committer date, which ought to be pretty safe at that point.)

Edit: Here's another approach. Expire the reflogs at the cutoff time, then delete the branches whose reflogs are empty. The problem here is that if the cutoff time is older than the time when your reflogs already expire (90 days) it'll really just be deleting branches older than 90 days instead. You could work around that, of course.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Git lets you use very readable time formats!
cutoff_time="1 year ago"
# other examples:
# cutoff_time="July 23, 2010"
# cutoff_time="yesterday"

git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname)' | egrep -v 'master|other-whitelisted-branch' |
while read branch; do
    git reflog expire --expire="$cutoff_time" $branch
    if [ "$(git reflog show -1 $branch | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
        git branch -D ${branch#refs/heads/}
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1: nice answer.  The example script has an error, though - `$branch` is the whole line, like "[object name] commit [ref name]" - you could do `git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname)'` instead.

Comment: Oh, and you get unsightly `[: : integer expression expected` errors unless you test for `$reflog_date` being empty (when the reflog has expired, as @cebewee says).  /me starts restoring all his old branches... ;)

Comment: @Mark: That actually suggests another way, which I thought of in the first place - you could expire the reflogs at the cutoff age, and then just check for empty reflogs. It's probably a little more elegant, but if you're not careful could unnecessarily prune some reflogs, e.g. for whitelisted branches you actually want to keep.

Comment: @Mark: Oh, as I was writing it up, I realized the other limitation. Those reflogs might be empty from the default expire time (90 days) which might be less than your cutoff time. Unnecessary branch deletion! The other approach keeps all those branches. Not sure which is better. It all takes more code to handle, so I'll leave it as-is for now.

Comment: Nice. It is worth noting that reflogs are not enable by default for bare repositories. It is easy to turn them on (`git config core.logAllRefUpdates true`), but, if they were not already enabled, the administrators would have to wait for another full “max age before deletion” period to pass before any branches would qualify for such automatic deletion.

Comment: The edited code snippet is now missing an `expire` with `git reflog` (e.g. should read `git reflog expire --expire="$cutoff_time" $branch` for any future readers to stumble across this answer.

Comment: @AeroEchelon Best way to help out future readers is to suggest edits! Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: @Jefromi Ah, I didn't know that! Thank you will do so in the future.

Answer (score 4):

*Update: as [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) and [cebewee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647987/cebewee) point out below, this solution looks at the 'committer date' of the commit at each branch tip, and in some situations this wouldn't be good enough - to use the former's example, if you care about branches which were recently created based on much older branches, you'd need to use the reflog as in [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396381/getting-git-branches-of-a-certain-age/5396755#5396755).  I think that for plenty of situations this is good enough, though, so I'm leaving the answer rather than deleting it...*

I did a [blog post](http://longair.net/blog/2011/03/14/git-too-many-topic-branches/) on this recently, with a script that lists branches in increasing order of the date of the last commit on that branch, which I've found useful for a very similar situation to yours.  The script is based around `git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for C in $(git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads --format='%(refname)')
do
    git show -s --format="%ci $C" "$C"
done
```

Comment: As I've written above, %ci is the wrong date -- it is the date of commit, not the date of the last change to the branch. This may differ in various cases, e.g. if you did a reset on branch, cherry-picked another commit, ...

Comment: @cebewee: the OP asks for a list of "the branches with heads of a given age" - I see what you're saying, but I think it's fair enough to interpret that as meaning "the date of the commit at the branch tip" rather than "the date when the ref was last changed".  I'll add a disclaimer though...

Comment: @cebewee: Using the committer date actually gets you nearly all of the benefit. A cherry-picked/rebased commit will have a refreshed committer date. But the big use case where the committer date would be old is a new branch created on an old commit, for testing/comparison purposes. It's a corner case, but it's worth handling.

Comment: To list branches tracking a remote called origin, use `refs/remotes/origin` instead of `refs/heads`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to script it and then use this to grab the date:

```
git log -1 branchName --format=%ci
```

this should give you date that you can order by.

Now you just need to iterate over the branches:

```
for branch in $(git branch -r); do yourscript $branch; done
```

hope this helps.

Comment: The date output by this command is *not* the date, where the branch was changed the last time, but the date of the last commit, which might be a very different thing.

Comment: git doesn't track the creation or modification of branches except in the reflog. This is close enough to what he wants. If he wants the date to reflect the last time using --no-ff merges and git commit --allow-empty should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up with this solution:

```
for k in $(git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/Your_prefix_here/{print $2}' | sed /\*/d); do
   if [ -z "$(git log -1 --since='Jul 31, 2015' -s origin/$k)" ]; then
     echo deleting "$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ct" origin/$k) origin/$k";
   fi;
done
```

Also It filters branches by a given patter, since we're using try-XX convention for branching.

Answer (score 0):

To find out when a branch last changed (opposed to the date of the last commit in a branch), you need to utilize the reflog. `git reflog branchName -1--date=relative` displays for a branch the newest reflog entry and the date of the last change to the branch.

There are various different date formats, choose one which is easy to parse for your use case.

A problem with this solution is that the reflog expires by default in IIRC 90 days. So, if the the last change on a branch is older then 90 days (and you dould a gc), you do not get any information about this branch. You circumvent this by changing the expire time for the reflog, see [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for this.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, which does not always work:

Just look at `.git/refs/heads/` and sort by modification date.

Note that this won't work if the repository is newer or something, as git simply doesn't track such information. But it might work very well in the future, when you have a central repository which otherwise doesn't change much.

Comment: There are pretty good odds of branches being stored in packed-refs instead - especially the old infrequently modified branches that we actually want to prune!

Comment: @Jefromi: Oh, didn't know that; never had that many branches :P

Comment: It's not exactly about quantity, though the reason for packing is boosting performance with large numbers of refs. `git gc` packs everything, but whenever a ref is created/updated it's unpacked. So branches tend to stay unpacked, but one that hasn't moved since the last `gc [--auto]` will only be found packed. Tags always stay packed, since they don't move!